# Failed to run android adv in terminal in Mac

Tags: android, virtual-device-manager

My operating system is MacOS and I am developing an android mobile app. I have downloaded the android studio and setup the android_home environment. I have installed the marshmallow6.0 SDK. I tried `android avd` in terminal and failed to open the avd.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument cannot be null
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.setText(Unknown Source)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdDetailsDialog.displayValue(AvdDetailsDialog.java:156)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdDetailsDialog.createContents(AvdDetailsDialog.java:73)
at com.android.sdkuilib.ui.SwtBaseDialog.open(SwtBaseDialog.java:93)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdSelector.onDetails(AvdSelector.java:964)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdSelector.access$600(AvdSelector.java:86)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdSelector$11.widgetDefaultSelected(AvdSelector.java:728)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.AvdManagerWindowImpl1.open(AvdManagerWindowImpl1.java:146)
at com.android.sdkuilib.repository.AvdManagerWindow.open(AvdManagerWindow.java:94)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showAvdManagerWindow(Main.java:438)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:380)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:151)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:117)
```

I don't know what `unknow source` means. Do I need to include some source files?

I try to open avd via android studio. But when I open the project, the ADV Manager is grey, which does not allow me to open adv. How can I fix this problem? Thank you so much.